# How to Flip widgets symmetrically inside ConstraintLayout using ConstraintSet with ChainStyle?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I've created 2 **recyclerView** inside **ConstraintLayout** that's constrained Horizontally with **chainStyle** `layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"`  however, i want to flip them symmetrically using **ConstraintSet** **Clear** and **Connect**.
When i'm trying to connect the widgets with **ConstraintSet** `CHAIN_SPREAD_INSIDE` this error appear

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: right to left undefined
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet.connect(ConstraintSet.java:1260)

, here's the figure that explains more this problem, thanks for the help.
[image]

> XML

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clScoreboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewVisitorTeam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/recyclerViewLocalTeam"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonContainer" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewLocalTeam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/recyclerViewVisitorTeam"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonContainer">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

> JAVA

```
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    ConstraintLayout clScoreboard = 
    rencontreView.findViewById(R.id.clScoreboard);
    set.clone(clScoreboard);
    //REVERSE PLAYERS TEAMS
    set.clear(R.id.recyclerViewLocalTeam, ConstraintSet.START);
    set.clear(R.id.recyclerViewLocalTeam, ConstraintSet.TOP);
    set.clear(R.id.recyclerViewLocalTeam, ConstraintSet.END);
    set.clear(R.id.recyclerViewLocalTeam, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

    set.clear(R.id.recyclerViewVisitorTeam, ConstraintSet.START);
    set.clear(R.id.recyclerViewVisitorTeam, ConstraintSet.TOP);
    set.clear(R.id.recyclerViewVisitorTeam, ConstraintSet.END);
    set.clear(R.id.recyclerViewVisitorTeam, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

    set.connect(R.id.recyclerViewLocalTeam, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.clScoreboard, ConstraintSet.END);
    set.connect(R.id.recyclerViewLocalTeam, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.buttonContainer, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    set.connect(R.id.recyclerViewLocalTeam, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.clScoreboard, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
```

> set.connect(R.id.recyclerViewLocalTeam, ConstraintSet.START,
>   R.id.recyclerViewVisitorTeam, ConstraintSet.END);

```
    set.connect(R.id.recyclerViewVisitorTeam, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.clScoreboard, ConstraintSet.START);
    set.connect(R.id.recyclerViewVisitorTeam, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.buttonContainer, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    set.connect(R.id.recyclerViewVisitorTeam, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.clScoreboard, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
```

> set.connect(R.id.recyclerViewVisitorTeam, ConstraintSet.END,
>   R.id.recyclerViewLocalTeam, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD_INSIDE);

```
    set.applyTo(clScoreboard);
```